# Windows 10 UWP Webview local url problems

Tags: c#, html, webview, uwp

Windows 10 UWP Webview

I have the two html files located in a www folder under Assets (Assets/www/xxx.html) in a Windows 10 UWP, both files in VS 2015 are set to be copied to the output dir.

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simple Script</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="submit.html" method="post">
    Data:<input type="text" name="somedata" > <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>

and submit.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dummy Submission</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2> Your data has been submitted - Thank You. </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

The Webview object is embbeded in the XMAL as below

```
<WebView  x:Name="WebBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="532" Width="1014" NavigationStarting="WebBrowser_NavigationStarting"/>
```

And the index page is loaded by

```
    /// Helper to perform the navigation in webview
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url"></param>
    private void NavigateWebview(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri targetUri = new Uri(url);
            WebBrowser.Navigate(targetUri);
        }
        catch (FormatException myE)
        {
            // Bad address
            WebBrowser.NavigateToString(String.Format("<h1>Address is invalid, try again.  Details --> {0}.</h1>", myE.Message));
        }
    }


NavigateWebview(@"ms-appx-web:///Assets/www/index.html");
```

The page loads and displays correctly but it will not display the linked 'submit.html' page, its just blank.

If I trap the Navigation event it does occur but appears to be prefixed by a GUID as show below.

[image]
I have changed paths to absolute etc and read the docs in detail but I fail to see why this does not work.

Ideas Please Guys ...

Comment: if submit is in same folder as index.html, then change your index.html to show as ms-appx-web://Submit.html and it should work.

Comment: Tried all combinations of file, URL etc. - all are visible in the navigation event but no page is shown. The two files work perfectly on all browsers tested - I just cant show a linked page in the Web view. All my other functions on the DOM work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I trap the Navigation event it does occur but appears to be prefixed by a GUID as show below

The "GUID" is the package name of current app, it is the default value of  **Authority** part of [URI schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/f3b3ae74-aaea-4f00-8f0a-4c231b8745af). So if you only want to navigate to another page, this absolutely path is right. You can test by code `NavigateWebview(@"ms-appx-web://{your package name}/Assets//www/submit.html");`

> The page loads and displays correctly but it will not display the linked 'submit.html' page, its just blank

For your issue, I change the `form` method to **get**, it will work.

```
<form action="submit.html"  method="get" id="myform">
    Data:<input type="text" name="somedata"> <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<a href="submit.html">Please Click Me to jump</a>
```

[`form`](http://html.com/attributes/form-method/) has two methods for submiting the form data. Get sends form data via a URL string, post sends form data via the server. In my opinion, post method post data firstly and then navigate, and the data are handled at server side. I haven't seen posted form data received and handled on a HTML page, so I guess you did not need use post method. For get method you can receive data and deal  them in javascript, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) is how to do.

Comment: Yes you are correct a change to get fixed this issue, may I ask where you leaned this information as I did not spot this as an issue in the ms docs.

Comment: @SarahT, This is not the uwp relative knowledge actually. I'm sorry I also haven't seen this information on uwp relative documents.  Just according to the HTML [form](http://html.com/attributes/form-method/)  tag definition that post requires server side support and may be I had experiences on writing code deal with post requirements code behind in a MVC project.

Comment: Many Thank - you have been a great help.